# Python Telegram Bot button entripoint for conversation

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i'm playing with Python Telegram Bot writing a simple bot to handle some conversation.

I try to evolve the sample code of inline keyboard found in docs page to get a conversation start when click on a specific InlineKeyboardButton.

Here my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=C0116,W0613
# This program is dedicated to the public domain under the CC0 license.

"""
First, a few callback functions are defined. Then, those functions are passed to
the Dispatcher and registered at their respective places.
Then, the bot is started and runs until we press Ctrl-C on the command line.
Usage:
Example of a bot-user conversation using ConversationHandler.
Send /start to initiate the conversation.
Press Ctrl-C on the command line or send a signal to the process to stop the
bot.
"""

import logging
import logging, pytz, datetime, time, os, telegram.bot
from telegram.utils.request import Request
from telegram.ext import messagequeue as mq
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update, ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler
from handlers.MainHandler import MainHandler
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
)

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION, BIO = range(4)


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")


def gender(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Stores the selected gender and asks for a photo."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Gender of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'I see! Please send me a photo of yourself, '
        'so I know what you look like, or send /skip if you don\'t want to.',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
    )

    return PHOTO


def photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Stores the photo and asks for a location."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    photo_file = update.message.photo[-1].get_file()
    photo_file.download('user_photo.jpg')
    logger.info("Photo of %s: %s", user.first_name, 'user_photo.jpg')
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Gorgeous! Now, send me your location please, or send /skip if you don\'t want to.'
    )

    return LOCATION


def skip_photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Skips the photo and asks for a location."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s did not send a photo.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'I bet you look great! Now, send me your location please, or send /skip.'
    )

    return LOCATION


def location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Stores the location and asks for some info about the user."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    user_location = update.message.location
    logger.info(
        "Location of %s: %f / %f", user.first_name, user_location.latitude, user_location.longitude
    )
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Maybe I can visit you sometime! At last, tell me something about yourself.'
    )

    return BIO


def skip_location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Skips the location and asks for info about the user."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s did not send a location.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'You seem a bit paranoid! At last, tell me something about yourself.'
    )

    return BIO


def bio(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Stores the info about the user and ends the conversation."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Bio of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text('Thank you! I hope we can talk again some day.')

    return ConversationHandler.END


def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    """Cancels and ends the conversation."""
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s canceled the conversation.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )

    return ConversationHandler.END


def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("MY_TOKEN")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Add conversation handler with the states GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION and BIO
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(button)],
        states={
            GENDER: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Boy|Girl|Other)$'), gender)],
            PHOTO: [MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo), CommandHandler('skip', skip_photo)],
            LOCATION: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.location, location),
                CommandHandler('skip', skip_location),
            ],
            BIO: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, bio)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i wonder to be able to click on the "Option 1" button to start a specific conversation funnel and on "Option 2" button to start another conversation funnel.

I found some refs on internet to modify the code on top but i'cant get it works.

Someone in this similar situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`CallbackQueryHandler(some_callback)` will handle *any* incoming `CallbackQuery`. You should make use of the `pattern` argument of [`CallbackQueryHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html). See also [this example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#inlinekeyboard2py).

Edit: Because you have two of `CallbackQueryHandler(some_callback)` (one inside the conversation, one outside), at most one of those can trigger for an update. Keep in mind the "order and priority counts" logic of [`Dispatcher.add_handler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Sure, to match only a specific button i'll use the pattern argument. But in the example show in the question unfortunately the ConversationHandler won't start after clicking on one of the button :(

Comment: The example showcases how the `pattern` argument can be used. To start a conversation on click of a button, you only need to use a `CallbackQueryHandler` as entry point - which you already do correctly

Comment: yes, the usage of pattern is quite simple. But the fisrt entripoint of the conversation is /start. I wonder to start the first step of conversationHandler with a click on the button. I'll'try to do "    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(button)]," but the convenrsation won't start while clicking on the button

Comment: that's because the callback query is already handled by the other `CallbackQueryHandler. see my edit ;)

Comment: thanks for the patience, removing the line "    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
" won't work too